# Replace substrings from a Dataframe column which correspond to values of another dataframe column with values of a third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace, substring

I have this huge dataset in which I have to replace each country's name with the corresponding ISO code. I have stored the ISO code of each country into another df.
e.g.

`df1`:

| TERRITORY |
| --- |
| France, Italy |
| Italy |
| Spain, France |
| France, Spain, Italy |

`df2`:

| COUNTRY | ISO CODE |
| --- | --- |
| France | FR |
| Italy | IT |
| Spain | ES |

Expected output:

| TERRITORY |
| --- |
| FR, IT |
| IT |
| ES, FR |
| FR, ES, IT |

My last try was to convert the element into tuples and then replace, but it doesn't work (and I don't know if it makes sense, but here's my code anyway):

```
country = tuple(list(df2['COUNTRY']))
iso = tuple(list(df2['ISO CODE']))
z = zip(x, y)

for x, y in z:
  if x in df1['TERRITORY']:
    df1['TERRITORY'].str.replace(x, y)
```

But it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of `.str.split` + `.explode`, then `.replace` + `.set_index`, and finally `.groupby(level=0)` + `agg(list)` + `.str.join`:

```
df1['TERRITORY'] = df1['TERRITORY'].str.split(', ').explode().replace(df2.set_index('COUNTRY')['ISO CODE']).groupby(level=0).agg(list).str.join(', ')
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
    TERRITORY
0      FR, IT
1          IT
2      ES, FR
3  FR, ES, IT
```

Comment: Woah, very useful and very quick, thank you very much, you saved me!
I'm new to this and I would've never figured it out without you!

Comment: how can I handle countries that are not in my df? 
for instance, if at line 2, df1 I got "Spain, France, Germany", in the final output it will display NaN. What if I want "ES, FR, Germany" as output?

Comment: Yep! That's really simple actually - all [I did](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71576252/revisions) was to change `.map` to `.replace`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the mapping you can also just use `replace()`:

```
df1.replace(df2.set_index('COUNTRY').squeeze(), regex=True)
```

Output:

```
    Territory
0      FR, IT
1          IT
2      ES, FR
3  FR, ES, IT
```

Comment: thank you very much! I make the same question to you:

how can I handle countries that are not in my df? 
for instance, if at line 2, df1 I got "Spain, France, Germany", in the final output it will display NaN. What if I want "ES, FR, Germany" as output?